# jQuery not calculating correct height of text if there is an orphaned word on line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

If you look at this page I'm developing: http://dev.aaronpitts.ch/test/ you will see three green buttons in rows saying 'Find out more'. I'm trying to get them to always be aligned using the following jQuery:

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$(".same-height-inner").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});

$(".same-height-inner").height(maxHeight);
```

The p block in .same-height-inner has a margin-bottom of 20px bottom but this isn't being included in the height of .same-height-inner. Also, if you look at this on a screen size of 1024 x 768 you will see the left hand column's text gets further miscalculation in height as it's not including the orphaned word which is broken to a new line. I've tried using

```
outerHeight(true)
```

but it makes no difference. How can I achieve the above?

Comment: In google chrome they are aligned on the first page at least.... or do you want to achieve this on the next page when you click find out more?

Comment: I think you shouldn't set the `height` but the `outerHeight` of the elements and also set it using `outerHeight`. If all else fails take a look at http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: they are aligned on the first page on larger screens when the text above is always two lines, but if you check on a 1024 x 768 screen for example, if there is an orphaned word causing a third line break it doesn't include that last line in the height

Comment: I've tried with outerheight, it makes no difference

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add .find('p') to your jQuery code, so it would be:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$(".same-height-inner").find('p').each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});
$(".same-height-inner").height(maxHeight);
```

The same way if you'r using outerHeight(true), for example, I'm using this code:

```
function calculateHeight($el) {
   var height = 0;
   $el.children().find('a').each(function() {
      height = height + $(this).outerHeight(true);
    });
   $el.data('oHeight', height);
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the paragraph element is larger than the enclosing div as it's an inline element inside a block element, just include the p in your selector

```
$(".same-height-inner p").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});

$(".same-height-inner").height(maxHeight);
```

You could alternatively make the enclosing div inline which will also fix the problem, but may have unintended consequences elsewhere on the site.

```
.same-height-inner {
    display: inline-block;
}
```